# How can I do this problem without using L'Hopital's rule or power series?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

> Let $a>0$ and
> $$g(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac {1 - a^x + xa^x \ln a} {a^x x^2}, & x<0 \\
> \dfrac {2^x a^x - x \ln 2 - x \ln a - 1} {x^2}, & x>0 \end{cases} .$$
> Without using L'Hopital's rule or power series, find the value of $a$ and $g(0)$ so that the function $g(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

---

I thought about it, but do not know where to begin.

Comment: would it be helpful to write all $xln(-)$ to be $ln(-^x)$?

Comment: You have to use the approximation $a^x-1 \sim x \ln a$.

Comment: @LiChunMin I could not understand what you mean

Comment: @Crostul this approximation came expansion which we have not to use

Comment: To *get started*, try to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0+}g(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0-}g(x)$.

Comment: poor title ...too general ...

Comment: @koolman Crostul's comment does not come from any series; it comes from the definition of the derivative of $a^x$ at $x=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: We know $(a^x)' = (\ln a) a^x.$ Thus the derivative of $a^x$ at $x=0$ is $\ln a.$ From the definition of the derivative we then have $a^x= 1 +(\ln a) x +o(x)$ as $x\to 0.$ (No L'Hopital or power series results were used.)

It follows from the FTC that

$$a^x = 1 +\int_0^x (\ln a) a^t \, dt = 1 +\int_0^x \ln a (1 +(\ln a) t +o(t))\,dt = 1 + (\ln a) x + (\ln a)^2x^2/2 + o(x^2).$$

Again, no Taylor or L'Hopital was used–just the definition of the derivative and the FTC.

This should allow you to solve the problem.

Comment: What is o(x) in the answer

Comment: $o(x^2)$ just means some function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)/x^2\to 0.$